# How to make this script upload image and zip files

Tags: php, mysqli, zip

M trying to make a upload and download script in which user uploads files and those are inserted into database.I know its not a good method but its the only method which worked out for me.
In the upload script it uploads files like .txt,.doc,etc but it wont upload zip files and image files..please help me.
here's the code for upload script

```
    <?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'myTable');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `file` (
                `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
            )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

here's the download script

```
<?php
    // Make sure an ID was passed
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Get the ID
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);

        // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
        if($id <= 0) {
            die('The ID is invalid!');
        }
        else {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'myTable');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            // Fetch the file information
            $query = "
                SELECT `mime`, `name`, `size`, `data`
                FROM `file`
                WHERE `id` = {$id}";
            $result = $dbLink->query($query);

            if($result) {
                // Make sure the result is valid
                if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                // Get the row
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                    // Print headers
                    header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
                    header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);

                    // Print data
                    echo $row['data'];
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
                }

                // Free the mysqli resources
                @mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
            else {
                echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
            }
            @mysqli_close($dbLink);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in .htaccess and check

```
AddType application/zip .zip
AddType image/gif .gif .GIF
AddType image/ief .ief
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG
AddType image/tiff .tiff .tif
```

It will enable the image and zip mime types.

Comment: where do I find it?I'm using wamp server

Comment: xampp/htdocs/'your application'/.htaccess is the path for that file. If there is no .htaccess file, you create one and add that.

Comment: I have tried what you have told..But still no use.Any other suggestions brother?

Comment: check upload_max_filesize in php.ini. Also check the size of the zip file you trying to upload

Comment: You are trying to use file_get_contents to get the file_contents for zip and image files before storing to database. For txt doc files file_get_contents will work and not for zip and image files. So change the 'data' fields in table to BLOB datatype and store the file as such without file_get_contents. And When you need retrieve from that and display.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't restricting uploads (it really should), so PHP configurations are probably responsible. The php.ini config file doesn't restrict uploaded file types, so the culprit is probably file size of images and zip files. Check the php.ini file (or use `phpinfo()`), and see what the maximum upload size is.

Comment: Its 64M..isn't that enough?